# Remove a temperature degree symbol

Tags: r, type-conversion, symbols

I have imported a .csv file that was output from a program and it uses the degree symbol when describing temperature units. For downstream subsetting purposes, I would like to remove the degree symbol and change it to a lower case "c". Below is a few rows of the data frame showing the problem.

```
all<-read.csv("/Users/VUE_Export.csv", header=T, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

all[10:15,]
    Date      DateTimeUTC    TagID  Value Unit StationName Latitude Longitude
10 7/23/2013 7/23/2013 19:57 13372 9.0799   °C     CB13-10 69.40534 -106.3001
11 7/23/2013 7/23/2013 19:59 13372 9.0799   °C     CB13-10 69.40534 -106.3001
12 7/23/2013 7/23/2013 20:04 13372 9.0799   °C     CB13-10 69.40534 -106.3001
13 7/23/2013 7/23/2013 20:04 13373 2.4255    m     CB13-10 69.40534 -106.3001
14 7/23/2013 7/23/2013 20:05 13372 9.0799   °C     CB13-10 69.40534 -106.3001
15 7/23/2013 7/23/2013 20:07 13372 9.0799   °C     CB13-10 69.40534 -106.3001
```

Intuitively, I would imagine it would be something like:

```
all$Unit[all$Unit==°C]<-"c"
```

I just don't know how to deal with the degree symbol. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: make sure to quote your strings: `all$Unit[all$Unit=="°C"]<-"c"`

Comment: `all$Unit <- gsub("°C","c",all$Unit)`?

Comment: Thanks for the help. This works great.